# Why declare types for each object variable in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

Since Objective-C is a dynamic typing language, why do we still need types?
Is the reason because it mixes with  C code?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555855/dynamic-typing-objective-c-how-does-it-work

Comment: It's not just mixed with C code, it's a strict superset of C.

Comment: You can, in theory, code everything as `id`, but you'd get yourself confused very quickly.  (It is true that Objective-C is a curious blend of strong typing and duck typing.  It's an odd beast.)

Comment: You are essentially correct -- when you use static typing (as other than a hint to the Objective-C preprocessor to avoid warning messages) you are using C, not the Objective-C extensions.  Objective-C itself does not *need* (or really even *use*) static types (though static types are helpful to humans to avoid coding bugs and general confusion).  The one exception to this is for scalar parameters on an Objective-C call (though one could argue that that's C, not Objective-C, since the parms are passed through the preprocessor essentially unchanged).

Answer (score 18):

Objective-C is not mixed with C, [it's a proper superset of C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963832/is-objective-c-2-0-a-proper-superset-of-c) with some [dynamic features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555855/dynamic-typing-objective-c-how-does-it-work).

You can avoid the use of static typing on any Objective-C object variable and declare everything as `id`, but I don't see why would you want to do that.
 You would lose all the help the compiler is giving you thanks to the type information (provided or inferred).

To wrap it up, you don't need types, you **want** types.

Comment: Exactly;  without strong typing of objects, what would be a compile time error turns into a runtime error, often at runtime in the hands of your [potential] customers....  Weakly typed languages *suck* for building complex applications.

Comment: @bbum - I wouldn't state it quite so strongly, but you have a point.

Comment: I wouldn't exactly call Objective-C a "superset" of C.  It's a SmallTalk-style language implemented via a sort of macro processor, running atop C.  That you can still "reach" C is something of a coincidence (though one that the developers take advantage of to avoid the need to fully implement the "guest" language).

Comment: The fact that you can "reach" C is exactly why it's a superset. It doesn't hide C, it includes it. From wiki: *it is possible to compile any C program with an Objective-C compiler, and to freely include C code within an Objective-C class*. Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963832/is-objective-c-2-0-a-proper-superset-of-c

Comment: @HotLicks Unlike C++, Objective-C **is** a superset of C.

Comment: In the same sense that printf is a superset of C.

Comment: @HotLicks `printf` wasn't a language last time I checked

Comment: Some would argue the same for Objective-C ;)

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C is a proper **superset** of C as it can do everything that C can do, and more. Initially Objective-C was created as an extension of C which compiled on any C compiler.

Types can both assist you as a programmer, as well as aid in the description of the language semantics. They prevent errors and can increase the performance of your application since the runtime system does not have to work as hard.

Comment: Where can static type information increase performance in Objective-C?

Comment: An example would be in a iterative construct. The runtime system would have to check on each iteration that the currently associated type of a variable can be used with boolean operators.

Comment: I don't really understand which scenario/language you describe but it's certainly not true for Objective-C. Its late binding means that on **each** message being sent the implementation of the method is being resolved from the selector again.

Comment: Basically, when you're using static typing you're using C, not Objective-C.  At most, static typing just clues the Objective-C preprocessor to produce the warning message that a method may not be available.